# Visual Studio C# code formatting: apply only some rules

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

We have been and still are using C++/CLI and Visual Studio 2008. Code formatting for C++ is very limited, but it had just those options that we needed.
CodeMaid v.0.4.3 (which was the latest to work with VS2008) was a good supplement to that, the combination of both worked really well.

Now we are migrating to Visual Studio 2015 and C#.
VS 2015 has a lot more options on code formatting and cleanup, especially for C#. But the whitespace options don't do what I need, e.g. vertical formatting of parameters on method definitions:

```
int Calculate (int    i_iInputValue1,
               int    i_iInputValue2,
               double i_dInputValue3)
{
  ...
}
```

will be "destroyed" because the spaces used for vertical alignment are removed.

**Is there any way to disable some formatting rules?**
I want VS not to touch the spaces there at all. On the other hand, other fromatting rules should be executed.
CodeMaid for VS 2015 is still an addition to the VS cleanup and formatting functions, it can't do the formatting that VS does.

If the formatting rules can't be disabled partially, then I am going to disable all of them and use 3rd-party software. **Which tool is able to do that?**
I have seen that CodeRush and Resharper to have a lot of functionality (haven't tested them yet), but I don't know whether vertial alignment is included. Resharper is quite expensive though.